# Is it possible to login/authenticate by URL link which is valid for a particular period of time? [NET Core 3.1 and Angular 9]

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1, autologin

As the topic says I would like to generate URL link (valid for a particular period of time) which would allow to authenticate with the web api (Core 3.1) just by click on it (user does not need to type login or password). After that generate JWT Baer Token to receive it from response and save it on website site (Angluar 9). Unfortunately I can not find any examples of that mechanism.

The token is generated by this method:

```
private string CreateBaererToken(IList<Claim> claims)
    {
        var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:SecretKey"]));
        var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var dateNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
            audience: _configuration["JWT:Audience"],
            notBefore: dateNow,
            claims: claims,
            expires: dateNow.AddHours(1),
            signingCredentials: signinCredentials
            );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);
    }
```

Comment: You are talking about magic links?

Comment: @BojanKogoj I guess so. Because I do not want to send any user credentials like email or password in query string parameters. Just generated some kind of secret key which will be valid for a particular period of time. But I would also want to keep recent possibility to log in by using email and password in a standard way.

Comment: There has to be a library with this functionality, it's pretty common. If nothing else, password reset / account activate links work this way in some frameworks.